# Jquery tablesorter: Place a row always last

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using this tablesorter:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Flexible-Client-Side-Table-Sorting-Plugin-tablesorter.html

I want to do one of two things.

More importantly:
- I have a "Total" row as my last row and I want it to not be sorted and to always just stay last.
I feel like this should be a feature on every sorter. Is it possible to do it?

And if really not, I'd like to disable sorting by a specific column. For some reason, I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: what happens if you add a `tfoot` element (outside of `tbody` so that it is a sibling of `tbody` and `thead`) and put the total row there? I'm not sure if the plugin will still pick that up or not as it only mentions `thead` and `tbody`.

Comment: Adding the row to the `tfoot` would be ideal. There is also a widget: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-static-row.html